# Uploading a blob to database in Java

Tags: java, oracle, image

I have written a java program where I can insert images to my Oracle database blob. It's working perfectly on other systems, but not working in my system when I want to insert an image of size greater than 2kb. But from my system I am able to retrieve images of any size. The same application is working well in other system but behaving abnormally, and some times can't read from socket exception when I try to insert a image bigger than 2 kb. Please help.

I am using typ4 driver.

Following is my table structure::

```
Name                                                  Null?    Type
----------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------
NAME                                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
DESCRIPTION                                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
IMAGE                                                 NOT NULL BLOB
```

The following is my Java program to insert the image. Again, it works on other systems in same network, which are connected to the same Oracle server. But from system showing problem when I try to upload an image having size more than 2kb.

```
package com.smruti.image;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.*;

public class InsertImage {
  private static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server3:1521:server3";
  private static String username = "system";
  private static String password = "manager";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    InputStream fis = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO pictures VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, "scare.jpg");
        stmt.setString(2, "scare image");

        File image = new File("C:\\images.jpeg"); 
        fis = new FileInputStream(image);
        int ilen=(int) image.length();
        System.out.println(ilen);
        System.out.println(fis);
        stmt.setBinaryStream(3, fis, ilen);
        stmt.execute();

        System.out.println("this is upto b4 commit");   
        conn.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some of your Java code?

Comment: You need to provide much more information, such as the table definition and the java code that inserts the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i too faced the same issue i could not upload more than 2kb file ... upadting the oracle jdbc driver to ojdbc5.jar resolved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[This external discussion thread](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=30048) indicates that it may be a jdbc driver issue. They recommend updating the oracle jdbc thin drivers.